# Javascript localStorage not working it overwrites object

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have 20 buttons and 20 links and descriptions inside info_array.
I add click event listener to each button.
On click function inside addEventListener must save unique info inside **localStorage** with incrementing object keys on each new button click.

Problem is that function works and saves Objects with unique value inside localStorage like 0,1,2,3,... till **10th** object. When object keys reach 10 then 11th object with key 11 is not saving  in localStorage, code just overwrites 10th object every time i clicked 11th,12th,13th,... button just overwrites value of 10th object rather creating and saving new object with new object key like 11,12,13,14,...

I can't understand what is wrong with my code because it works till 10th object.

**Code:**

```
for (let i = 0; i < 19; ++i) {

    let btn = document.createElement('BUTTON');

    btn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();

        let newsList = localStorage,
        keys         = Object.keys(localStorage).sort(),
        match        = false,
        news         = {
            "title":info_array[i].title,
            "description":info_array[i].description
        };

        if (nl.length > 0) {

            // check if element exists in localStorage
            for(let n = 0; n < newsList.length; ++n){
                if (JSON.parse(newsList[keys[n]]).link == info_array[i].link) {
                    match = true;
                }
            }

            // if object is unique save in localStorage
            if (!match) {
                let key = (parseInt(keys.pop())+1).toString();
                localStorage.setItem(key,JSON.stringify(news));
            }
            
        }else{
            // if localStorage is empty add first object
            localStorage.setItem(0,JSON.stringify(news));
        }

    },{passive:true});

    html.appendChild(element);
}
```

Comment: `keys.pop()` will not only access but also _remove_ the last element of the array - I don't think you want this to happen. ;)

Comment: On a separate note, `localStorage.setItem(0, value)` doesn't set the first item in localStorage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of this line:

```
keys = Object.keys(localStorage).sort()
```

Specifically, the bug is caused by `.sort()`

Strings are sorted in **dictionary** order. So your keys are:

```
0, 1, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

This logic is similar to how the words

```
app, big, branch, cut, dig, eye, fig, gem
```

are sorted. The word `branch` comes afer `big` and not `gem` because it starts with `b`. Similarly `10` comes after `1` and not `9` because it starts with the **letter** `1`.

When you pop the last key and add 1 to it you will get `10` because the last key is always `9`.

Comment: you are my savior <3 you are correct problem was sort() function, so i changed keys   = Object.keys(localStorage).sort() to keys   = Object.keys(localStorage).sort(function(a, b) {return a - b;}) and code works now thanks